# Uniform convergence of $ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x\cdot\sin\sqrt {x/n}} {n + x} $

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, uniform-convergence

I need to check on the uniform convergence. 
$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x\cdot\sin\sqrt {\frac x n}} {n + x} $$

on the interval:

a) $\; (0, 1) $

b) $\; (1, +\infty) $

I think I need to use Cauchy ratio, but I cannot understand how

Comment: Cauchy wont work, try majorizing by $\frac{1}{n^2}$

Comment: Use: $sin(a) ~ a + o(a)$

Comment: Actually $sin(a) < a + o(a)$

Comment: Or you could use Dirichlet test

Comment: opps didnt see the square root, majorize by $\frac{1}{n^{\frac{3}{2}}}$ using the above estimates for $\sin$.

Comment: @ Mihail Salnikov : what is cauchy ratio test for uniform convergence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For part $(a)$:

$$\begin{align}
\left|\sum _{n=1}^\infty \frac{x\sin {\sqrt {\frac{x}{n}}}}{n+x}\right| &\le \sum _{n=1}^\infty \left|\frac{x\sin {\sqrt {\frac{x}{n}}}}{n+x}\right|\\\\
&\le  \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\left|x\,\sqrt{\frac{x}{n}}\right|}{n+x}\,\,\text{since} |\sin x|\le |x|\\\\
&\le \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left|\frac{x^{\frac{3}{2}}}{n^{\frac{1}{2}}(n+x)}\right|\\\\
&\le \left|\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^{\frac{3}{2}}}{n^{\frac{3}{2}}}\right|\\\\
&\le \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{\frac{3}{2}}} \to 0 
\end{align}$$

provided $|x|<1$

By Weistrass M Test we have the series converges uniformly.

Comment: on $ x \in (1, +\infty) $ p = 1 and $x = \pi n^2$ by Cauchy

Comment: @ Learnmore : what did you say about the uniform convergence on $(1, + \infty)$